# JS waiting for response

Tags: javascript, callback, alert

I want to replace JS alert and confirm buttons. The major reason for this is a checkbox 'Prevent dialogs on this window', which is most times automatically chosen by users! :)

So, on click on the button a modal window appears, but the function doesn't wait user response.

I don't want to use Jquery UI plugins, and don't now how to use callbacks for this problem.

Could you help, please?

**UPDATE**

```
my_function(){
if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
 {
   ** do something **
 }
}
```

**So, I want to replace confirm writing a new local function, which will replace the function above:**

```
confirm('text'){
** Do something **
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a single threaded language. There are only a couple occasions where you can 'block' the thread of execution which are '[alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)', '[confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)', and '[prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)'.Other scenario require an asynchronous callback.

The [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object makes handling asynchronous logic easier and it's [available](http://caniuse.com/#search=promise) for most browsers natively and support for all browsers exists via a [shim](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).

There are also many libraries that offer richer modals over the standard browser modal.

Regardless of the approach you want, you need to learn about callbacks and asynchronous programing for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, good.
Could you please look also here 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812807/php-html-issue-with-quotes'?

Answer (score 2):

`window.confirm` is synchronous (waits for user input) function because it is natively implemented. You can redefine this function but there is no way to implement confirm dialog synchronously (without callbacks). You should consider using [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or something else

Comment: The modal doesn't wait for user response before continuing

Comment: @TarlanMamedzade review this answer: "there is no way to implement confirm dialog synchronously (without callbacks)." Any user written replacement for a blocking dialog such as alert` or confirm will not be synchonous and wait for user input.

Comment: I don't care about the method. I need result. May you suggest a way of doing that, describing it deeper?

Comment: it is impossible - neither  with `confirm` method nor something else

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use callbacks?
Could you try using an event listener on the submit button to call that function?

`function doSomething(){
   var text = document.querySelectory("#answer").val;
   console.log("You answered "+text)
}`

`<input id="answer" type="text"><button onclick="doSomething()">`

Comment: Create a reduced test case on https://plnkr.co/ or some similar service so we can test how it should work

Comment: In your example I have to rewrite all functions where confirm is used. What I want is to create a local function, which automatically will replace JS confirm